# Вызов функции из соседнего фрейма в Opera

Tags: opera, javascript

Нужно в Opera вызвать функцию из другого iframe'a (**домен тот же**).
Говорят, напрямую из фрейма в фрейм не надо лезть, а надо сделать в главном контейнере функцию по вызову цели и вызывать её из нужного места. Но не тут то было.

`Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: testFunc` - это для кода:

```
top.testFunc(text);
```

Что можно сделать с этим?

Comment: А может у фреймов домен тот-же а у главной страницы другой?

Comment: @Rules, нет. К тому же, он спотыкается уже на обращении к функции главного, а не когда главный идёт к цели.

Comment: А если написать не:

    top.testFunc(text);

а:

    top.window.testFunc(text);

?

Comment: @Rules, не работает.

Comment: Поищите [здесь](http://javascript.ru/ "JavaScript.ru") там есть ПРО ВСЁ что касается JavaScript  
P.S преобразовано из ответа т.к ответ был не достойный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли решить. Проблема была не в JS коде. Мой локальный сервер для тестирования использовал домен [localhost.com](http://localhost.com)
Он в чёрных списках Opera (я захожу через неё), т.к. на таком реальном адресе обманный сайт находится какой-то. Вот так Опера обеспечивала безопасность.
Поменял в /etc/hosts адрес локального сервера на другой (не подозреваемый в нарушениях), и всё заработалл. Первый раз я обиделся на Оперу: полдня искал, что за фигня.
Может кому-то пригодится это.